# Declaring and using a module without a struct

Tags: rust

I have the following module without a struct:

**img_util.rs:**

```
pub mod img_util {
    use image::{ImageBuffer, Pixel};
    use std::{fs::File, io::BufWriter};

    fn get_color_type<P>() -> Result<png::ColorType, std::io::Error>
    where
        P: Pixel<Subpixel = u8>,
    {
        match <P as Pixel>::CHANNEL_COUNT {
            4 => Ok(png::ColorType::Rgba),
            3 => Ok(png::ColorType::Rgb),
            _ => Err(std::io::Error::new(
                std::io::ErrorKind::InvalidData,
                "Incorrect color channel count / format.",
            )),
        }
    }

    fn get_dpi_header_data(dpi: u32) -> Vec<u8> {
        let dpm = 39.370079 * dpi as f32;
        let rounded_dpm = dpm.round() as u32;

        let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        data.extend_from_slice(&rounded_dpm.to_be_bytes()); // Pixels per unit in X-direction.
        data.extend_from_slice(&rounded_dpm.to_be_bytes()); // Pixels per unit in Y-direction.

        data.push(1); // Indicate that meters are used as unit.
        data
    }

    pub fn save_png_with_dpi<P>(
        input_img: &ImageBuffer<P, Vec<u8>>,
        output_img: File,
        dpi: u32,
    ) -> Result<(), std::io::Error>
    where
        P: Pixel<Subpixel = u8>,
    {
        let w = &mut BufWriter::new(output_img);
        let (width, height) = input_img.dimensions();
        let mut encoder = png::Encoder::new(w, width, height);

        encoder.set_color(get_color_type::<P>()?);
        encoder.set_depth(png::BitDepth::Eight);
        encoder.set_compression(png::Compression::Best);

        let data = get_dpi_header_data(dpi);
        let mut writer = encoder.write_header()?;

        writer.write_chunk(png::chunk::pHYs, data.as_slice())?;
        writer.write_image_data(input_img)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

**lib.rs:**

```
pub mod img_util;
```

**main.rs:**

```
use visual_center::img_util::img_util;

img_util::save_png_with_dpi(
    // arguments
).unwrap();
```

I can use the module, but I feel strange about having to declare pub mod img_util twice (once in `img_util.rs` and another in `lib.rs`). Or maybe this is the only way to declare and use a module without a struct?

Comment: `mod {}` inside a file is primarily used to declare multiple modules per file. Since your whole module is exactly contained in `img_util.rs`, just remove redundant `pub mod img_util { }` from `img_util.rs` and you should be good to go

Comment: `pub mod img_util;` in `lib.rs` should be present, in order to make this module visible for users of the library. The use statement should then be just `use visual_center::img_util;`

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Thanks, could you post an answer?

Comment: No need, the comment is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `pub mod img_util;` in `lib.rs`, the compiler will consider `img_util.rs` as a module of your crate.
Everything in `img_util.rs` is already in the `img_util` module.
If you state `pub mod img_util { ... }` in this module, this means that you provide (inline, not in another file) a **sub**module with the exact same name as its parent (this is a coincidence here, you could have named it differently).

You just have to remove this `pub mod img_util { ... }`.
Then you will use it in `main.rs` as

```
use visual_center::img_util; // one less

img_util::save_png_with_dpi(
    // arguments
).unwrap();
```